# WAMP 500 Internal Server Error .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I know there are lots of topics there about this error, but i hope you can help.

here's the error message:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I think the problem is caused by .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 messagebrd.pl index.html index.htm# disable directory browsing
Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes**
```

Comment: So far we can only _guess_ which does not make much sense. The first thing you _always_ should do when you encounter such problems is to look into the error log file of your http server. That is where details about such issues are logged to. Knowing those details it should be possible to solve them. For the location of that log file check the configuration / documentation of your http server (apache inside WAMP AFAIK). Under unixoid systems that is typically something like `/var/log/apache2/error_log` or similar, not sure how that is mapped on the MS-Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Server 500 errors can be quite a hassle to diagnose, but if you think its the .htaccess file that is causing the problem you need to work out which line is the problem by a simple process of elimination.

Start by removing the .htaccess file, and start apache
Then add one line at a time to the htaccess file restarting apache after each change.

When apache fails to start then you know what line in .htaccess it is that is causing the problem